# No encuentra la URL en php

Tags: php, html

Tengo este botón:

```
echo "<td>  <a href='./update.php=".$filas['idcompra']."'> <button type='button' /class='btn btn-success'>Ver_Registro</button> </a> </td>";
```

para que cuando le de clic, me salga la información de ese id, pero me tira el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuál es el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De entrada, la forma de construir la URL del vínculo parece incorrecta.

La manera correcta de hacer una petición GET a un script php desde un vínculo, con una ruta relativa es:

```
la/ruta/al/recurso/NombreDelRecurso.php?variable1=valor1&variable2=valor2&etc=etc
```

Se debe utilizar un signo `?` entre la extensión del recurso y su primer parámetro, y luego separar los parámetros con un signo `&`. Está bien iniciar la ruta con `./`, aunque no hace falta.

Si observas, el error está en que estás poniendo un signo igual directamente después de la extensión `php` y, supongo que el servidor web lo toma como parte del nombre del recurso y por eso da error 404.

Con la información actual, es difícil decir específicamente cuál sería la forma de *corregir* la dirección, pero suponiendo que el script espera un parámetro llamado `idcompra`, podría ser algo como:

```
echo "<td><a href='./update.php?idcompra=".$filas['idcompra']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Ver_Registro</button></a></td>"
```

Si observas, también he quitado una `/` que estaba de más en la declaración del botón.

Answer (score 0):

El error es que te falta dos cosas en la URL. La primera es el carácter **?** que sirve para definir que es una URL del tipo GET. (Básicamente explicado).

Luego de eso, lo más importante es que no defines una variable que se pueda recoger en el destino.

He replicado tu código con las correcciones.

```
<?php

   $fila = 1;

   echo "<td>  <a href='./update.php?id=".$fila."'> <button type='button' /class='btn btn-success'>Ver_Registro</button> </a> </td>";

?>
```

Y en el otro archivo

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_GET);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Resultado

> Array
> (
> [id] => 1
> )